# Register block pattern category with higher priority

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to register a block pattern category and display it on top of the block pattern categories list. However, it is not working. Is there a way to do that?

[image: Pattern Categories List in the Block editor]

```
function prefix_register_block_patterns() {
    $block_pattern_categories = array(
        'prefix' => array( 'label' => __( 'My Pattern category', 'prefix' ) ),
    );

    $block_pattern_categories = apply_filters( 'prefix_block_pattern_categories', $block_pattern_categories );

    foreach ( $block_pattern_categories as $name => $properties ) {
        if ( ! WP_Block_Pattern_Categories_Registry::get_instance()->is_registered( $name ) ) {
            register_block_pattern_category( $name, $properties );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_register_block_patterns', 9 );
```

Comment: reading the PHP code on the official WP dev docs implies that the categories are inherently unordered and stored as key value pairs or name => properties, there's a very high chance that what you're trying to achieve isn't possible

Comment: The Gutenberg JS code provides no methods for this, and doesn't attempt to sort things, it seems it just uses the order returned by the REST API. REST API pattern categories appear second, and a separate section appears first which is why there are two distinct alphabetically listed pattern categories from the top down: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/ce4dd6167517ed52de1a120ee4015942a7f73513/packages/editor/src/components/provider/use-block-editor-settings.js#L159-L169

Comment: there is no sorting in the REST API either https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-block-patterns-controller.php#L104

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible via `register_block_pattern_category` or filter priorities.

Gutenberg and the REST API at the time of writing don't attempt to sort the categories, and instead display them in the order given to them by the Pattern repository class in PHP.

That pattern repository class stores them in an array as objects on keys, so they are not numerically indexed and sortable in the traditional sense. But even if they were, that array is `private` and unmodifiable:

```php
private $registered_categories = array();
```

And the class is `final`:

```php
final class WP_Block_Pattern_Categories_Registry {
```

And referenced directly by name, so it can't be swapped out.

The best and only remaining hope is to use REST API filters to re-sort the JSON response how you prefer, but this is unlikely to bring it to the very top, this is because REST API pattern categories are always second after an internal list of categories registered via javascript.

This is why featured/posts/text/gallery appear first followed by the rest.